# How to handle a question from an end user?

Tags: discussion

I was going through the review queue and [Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306375/error-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-byte) was presented to me.  The OP is an end user and they are getting an exception on a website they use on their laptop.  They want to know if something is wrong with their laptop since their other devices work fine.  Is this something that is on topic on SO?  If not how should we handle it.

Comment: Well this website is not a helpdesk, it also isn't meant for questions that are only specific to your own situation.. so I would say downvote / vote to delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a programming question, it's a question about using a site (in a non-programming context) so it's off topic on SO.

It *might* be able to be turned into an on topic question on [Web App](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).  (Note I'm not a member of that site, so see their help center to determine if it is fact appropriate there.)  And even if it could become an on topic question there, it's certainly not a suitable one *yet*.

Comment: Now it's closed.